# C# Listview Editing all at once

Tags: c#, listview

Is it possible to have a button that allows all the rows within a listview to be edited at once instead of just one row at a time?

Sorry this would be for ASP.NET, Webform.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do it. You simply have to reload the entire listview after the modifications.

Comment: What kind of GUI are we talking about? ASP.NET? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: ASP.NET is the flavor used here.